# Query not inserting into database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, prepared-statement

I have two queries in the code I am showing. The first one gets users from my database users and then shuffles the results. The second one, I am trying to INSERT the shuffled results into the database user_players. However, my second query is not doing anything.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `group` = 3");

echo 'Users to be given draft order: <br>';
$array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $array[] = $row;
    echo $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'] . '<br>';
}
?>
<form method="POST" name="form">
    <input type="submit" value="Create Draft Order" name="shuffle">
</form>

    Shuffled results: <br>
    <div class="main-bag">     
    <div class="shuffle_results" id="results"></div>
         <img id='paperBag' src="http://www.thecuriouscaterpillar.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/a/bag_to_white.jpg" width="200px" />
```

Where it stops working and doesn't send to database

```
    <form method="post">
         <input type="submit" value="Finalize Draft Order" name="insert">
    </form>

 <?php
      foreach ($array as $result) {
        $shuffle_firstname = htmlentities($result['firstname']);
        $shuffle_lastname = htmlentities($result['lastname']);
        $shuffle_id = htmlentities($result['id']);
        $shuffle_username = htmlentities($result['username']);
        $shuffle_email = htmlentities($result['email']);
        ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="firstname[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_firstname; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="lastname[]" value="<?php //echo $shuffle_lastname; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_id; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="username[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_username; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="email[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_email; ?>">
<?php 
}        
if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $stmt2 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO user_players (user_id, firstname, lastname, username, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    if ( false===$stmt2 ) {
         // Check Errors for prepare
        die('Add to user players prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
    $stmt2->bind_param('issss', $shuffle_id, $shuffle_firstname, $shuffle_lastname, $shuffle_username, $shuffle_email);

    foreach ($_POST['id'] as $i => $shuffle_id) {
        $shuffle_firstname = $_POST['firstname'][$i];
        $shuffle_lastname = $_POST['lastname'][$i];
        $shuffle_username = $_POST['username'][$i];
        $shuffle_email = $_POST['email'][$i];
        $stmt2->execute() or
            die('Add to user players execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));
```

An error I get is this..

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

for this line

```
foreach ($_POST['id'] as $i => $shuffle_id) {
```

What am I doing wrong and why is that argument invalid?

When I put the `</form>` and submit button after the inputs, the submit button gets put inside of my loop..

```
<form method="post">




<?php
      foreach ($array as $result) {
        $shuffle_firstname = htmlentities($result['firstname']);
        $shuffle_lastname = htmlentities($result['lastname']);
        $shuffle_id = htmlentities($result['id']);
        $shuffle_username = htmlentities($result['username']);
        $shuffle_email = htmlentities($result['email']);
        ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="firstname[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_firstname; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="lastname[]" value="<?php //echo $shuffle_lastname; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_id; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="username[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_username; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="email[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_email; ?>">
        <input type="submit" value="Finalize Draft Order" name="insert">
           </form>
```

Comment: Try dumping the contents of `$_POST['id']` with `var_dump()` to see what comes out...

Comment: Your `<form>` does not contain the input fields. Move the `</form>` to after the input fields

Comment: *Nice catch there Smokey* - @RiggsFolly

Comment: I did this... not sure if it is correct, ` $stmt2->bind_param('issss', $shuffle_id, $shuffle_firstname, $shuffle_lastname, $shuffle_username, $shuffle_email);
var_dump('id');
    foreach ($_POST['id'] as $i => $shuffle_id) {` and I got `string(2) "id" `

Comment: @RiggsFolly when I do that my Finalize button disappears and if I move the submit button above the `</form>` after the inputs, it gets put into the loops.

Comment: I have written my comment as an answer as it appeared to cause you some confusion

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you actually did in response to my comment but this I believe should make the `<form>` contain all the required html input and the button.

```
    <form method="post">
<?php
    foreach ($array as $result) :
        $shuffle_firstname = htmlentities($result['firstname']);
        $shuffle_lastname = htmlentities($result['lastname']);
        $shuffle_id = htmlentities($result['id']);
        $shuffle_username = htmlentities($result['username']);
        $shuffle_email = htmlentities($result['email']);
?>
        <input type="hidden" name="firstname[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_firstname; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="lastname[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_lastname; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_id; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="username[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_username; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="email[]" value="<?php echo $shuffle_email; ?>">

<?php 
    endforeach;
    // only show this button if we have done a shuffle
    if ( isset($_POST['shuffle'] ) ) :
        echo '<input type="submit" value="Finalize Draft Order" name="insert">';
    endif;
?>            
    </form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $stmt2 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO user_players (user_id, firstname, lastname, username, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    if ( false===$stmt2 ) {
         // Check Errors for prepare
        die('Add to user players prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
    $stmt2->bind_param('issss', $shuffle_id, $shuffle_firstname, $shuffle_lastname, $shuffle_username, $shuffle_email);

    foreach ($_POST['id'] as $i => $shuffle_id) {
        $shuffle_firstname = $_POST['firstname'][$i];
        $shuffle_lastname = $_POST['lastname'][$i];
        $shuffle_username = $_POST['username'][$i];
        $shuffle_email = $_POST['email'][$i];
        $stmt2->execute() or
            die('Add to user players execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));
```

Comment: Awesome! that worked! If I wanted to finalize button to not show until the create draft button is pressed. How can I do that? Do I just wrap that form an in `if (isset9$_POST['insert']))` ?

Comment: I am not totally sure I am guessing you did not post the complete script so I cannot be sure

Comment: I have all of the relevant code to that. I just want this ` <input type="submit" value="Finalize Draft Order" name="insert">` to not appear until the first submit button is pressed `<form method="POST" name="form">
    <input type="submit" value="Create Draft Order" name="shuffle">
</form>`

Comment: Try that see if its what you want. I have added a test to only show the button if the `shuffle` button was pressed

Comment: I get this error... Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':'

Comment: Woops missed a closing bracket, see `if ( isset($_POST['shuffle'] ) ) :`

Comment: It still shows on the page before I click on the shuffle button.

Comment: Like I said, in order to be sure what I am doing I would need to see the complete script, right now I am kinda guessing based on what you showed us, but I have no idea what goes on in what you left out

Comment: I didn't leave anything out of it. I copied and pasted it right in.

Comment: Try running the form in a clean state as if it was run for the first time. I think you are F5'ing it and its running as if the Shuffle button was already pressed

Comment: I'm not F5'ing it. I left the page, came back and even signed off and on.

Answer (score 0):

`$con` is the link identifier. You have to pass it to `mysqli_prepare` method.

Please call

```
$stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user_players (user_id, firstname, lastname, username, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

instead of

```
$stmt2 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO user_players (user_id, firstname, lastname, username, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

Comment: I'm sorry - I checked the documentation again. Using $con->prepare will not cause an error, but I think that it's nicer to use object-oriented style OR procedural style. In the above code @Ralph always is using mysqli_* function. So my "answer" is not an answer - it should be a comment...